# Owner-drawn button with BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON style

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, ownerdrawn

How do I get the checked/unchecked state of BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON? My code currently doesn't work.

```
void CPngButton::DrawItem( LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS )
{
    ASSERT(lpDIS != NULL);

    UINT state = lpDIS->itemState;
    if (state & ODS_CHECKED)
    {
    // do stuff
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
if (BST_CHECKED == SendMessage(BM_GETCHECK))
```

but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ODS_CHECKED only applies to menus. BM_GETCHECK and BM_GETSTATE can both provide the checked state:

```
if (Button_GetState(lpDIS->hwndItem) & BST_CHECKED)
```

Comment: Note that you'll need to have included `windowsx.h` in order to use the `Button_GetState` macro.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92fhtw0f.aspx), the `ODS_CHECKED` flag is only applicable to menu items:

> **`ODS_CHECKED`**   This bit is set if the menu item is to be checked. This bit is used only in a menu.

Instead, to determine the checked state of a button, you should call the [`CButton::GetCheck` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tba1y6f.aspx). It will return one of the following values:

> **`BST_UNCHECKED`**           The button is unchecked
>
> **`BST_CHECKED`**               The button is checked
>
> **`BST_INDETERMINATE`**   Button state is indeterminate
>   (only if `BS_3STATE` or `BS_AUTO3STATE` set).

For example:

```
CButton myBtn;
if (myBtn.GetCheck() = BST_CHECKED)
{
    // Drawing code here...
}
```